# Proper way to use UIImageView inside a custom View class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I want to use a method from Appearable protocol on my custom View.

```
protocol Appearable { }

extension Appearable where Self: UIView { 

    func appear(duration: Double, delay: Double) {
        self.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.0, y: 1.5)
        }, completion: nil)

        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
}
```

My CustomView:

```
class CustomView: UIView, Appearable {}
```

In my MainView I have created variable with an image that i want to show on screen.

```
class MainView: UIView {
    let randomView: CustomUIView = {
    var image = CustomUIView()
    image = UIImageView(image: myImage)

    return image
}
```

This code ll not work because cannot assign value of type 'UIImageView' to type 'CustomView'. My question is, what is a proper way to do this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not creating a CustomImageView class and conforming to Appearable protocol?

```
class CustomImageView: UIImageView, Appearable {}
```

now you can do what you need:

```
let imageView = CustomImageView()
imageView.image = myImage
```

and use default protocol method:

```
imageView.appear(duration: 2.0, delay: 0.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does work. But what id I would have inherit from UIView and then do the same thing? Is there better option than casting image to my custom class?

Comment: @Billy you've tried to cast UIView extended with your protocol to UIImageView. UIImageView extends UIView, it has adjusted API and it would be inappropriate to do such cast. If you want your protocol method to be called on UIImageView class make a custom UIImageClass and conform to protocol.

Comment: Got it. Thank you again.